# OpenShift authentication server for tools Git/JENKINS/JFROG

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, openshift, openid-connect, auth0

I have an OpenShift cluster 4.7 in IBM CLOUD that runs many infrastructure tools ( Jenkins, Gitea, JFrog, SonarQube, WIKIJS, etc etc). I want to be able to login  to these tools using my OpenShift credentials. Do you have any working way to use OpenShift's integrated OAUTH server to do so? Or any other idea?

I know Jenkins has already a plugin to do so, but what about the rest? Is auth-proxy the best way? Cause most of my tools have been installed with HelmCharts or Operators and I am not sure how easy is it gonna be to configure something like that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably, you can use product "keycloak"
   https://www.keycloak.org/gettin.../getting-started-openshift
   In my opinion it is more likely to use KeyCloak.
2. In addition, you can consider IBM Cloud   product AppID. You can find it In IBM Cloud catalog using link https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/app-id.

Comment: 1) Yeap I used Keycloak to tackle my issue here. As the project goes on I will try to dig into it and find a way.
2) IBM Cloud AppID is like keycloak. It has a separate database for the applications. So it does not cover more needs than the Keycloak that I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the official documentation on this?

[Configuring OAuth client](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/authentication/configuring-oauth-clients.html)
[Configuring the internal OAuth server](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html)

Comment: Yeap I did with no luck. I will have to dig into it more.